# Need help to write f:N->N in prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, iteration

I'm suppose to write f:N->N

```
f(0)=2,f(1)=0,f(2)=3
f(n)=3f(n-3)+2f(n-2)-(n-1) for n>=3.
```

both iteratively and recursively,

This is what I have so far iteratively but i keep getting 3 for N>2

```
f(0,2).
f(1,0).
f(2,3).
f(N,F) :-
   N>2,
   N1 is N-1,
   N2 is N-2,
   N3 is N-3,
   f(N1,F1),
   f(N2,F2),
   f(N3,F3),
   F4 is F2*2,
   F6 is F3*3,
   F5 is F4+F6,
   F is F5-F1.
```

Any help you can give me is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20012913/writing-a-factorial-like-function-prolog/20013114#20013114

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me!

```
?- f(5,X).
X = 12 .

?- f(6,X).
X = 3 .

?- f(7,X).
X = 30 .

?- f(8,X).
X = 12 .
```

Maybe you just tried with a lot values that return 3?

Also, you could have done:

```
f(N,F) :- N>2, N1 is N-1, N2 is N-2, N3 is N-3,
          f(N1,F1), f(N2,F2), f(N3,F3),
          F is 3*F3 + 2*F2 - F1.
```